# Javamail send message from 2 smtp servers

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a problem and need some help

In my program I need to send a mail and smtp server depends of one var, 
if var is 1 then must send mail from a gmail address
or if var is 2 the mail is send from a diferent smtp server

I use TLS from both accounts and all is ok (if only send from 1 server)... but when I try to send from both servers (because my var change depend from 1 to 2, or 2 to 1 many times during the execution) I recieved always an error

Here my code:

```
public static void correo(String empresa, String[] dest, String archivo, String nom_arch){
    String cuenta = "", asunto = "", pw = "", pto = "", server = "";
    try
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        if("1".equals(empresa)){
            cuenta = "example@gmail.com";
            asunto = "xxxxxxx";
            pw = "password";
            pto = "587";
            server = "smtp.gmail.com";
        }
        else if ("2".equals(empresa)) {
            cuenta = "example@server.com";
            asunto = "yyyyyyy";
            pw = "password";
            pto = "25";
            server = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
        }

        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", server);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", pto);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", cuenta);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);

        BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
        texto.setText("Some Text");

        BodyPart adjuntoPDF = new MimeBodyPart();
        adjuntoPDF.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(archivo+".pdf")));
        adjuntoPDF.setFileName(nom_arch+".pdf");

        MimeMultipart multiparte = new MimeMultipart();
        multiparte.addBodyPart(texto);
        multiparte.addBodyPart(adjuntoPDF);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(cuenta));

        InternetAddress[] direcciones = new InternetAddress[dest.length];
        for(int i=0; i<dest.length; i++){
            direcciones[i] = new InternetAddress(dest[i]);
        }
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,direcciones);
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        message.setContent(multiparte);

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect(cuenta, pw);
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        t.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this JavaMail FAQ list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance.